# curl via Jenkins only works sometimes

Tags: curl, jenkins, proxy, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I want to upload some files via ftp using `curl` command inside Jenkins Pipeline. The command I use looks like this:

```
sh "curl --verbose -T my.file --proxytunnel --proxy http://${PROXY_USER}:${PROXY_PASS}@MYPROXY:MYPROXYPORT ftp://${AZURE_USER}:${AZURE_PASS}@MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net/site/wwwroot/"
```

Sometimes, I click on "Build"-button in Jenkins 5 times in a row and all 5 builds are successful. Then, 10 minutes later, I click again the build-button and it fails 5 times in a row - without changing anything inside the Jenkins Job!

So it looks to me as if there is sometimes some kind of session cached and sometimes not. But I don't know which kind of session, because I set `{http|https|ftp|no}_proxy`, `PROXY_USER` and `AZURE_USER`.

Here is the error message when the build fails:

```
* About to connect() to proxy MYPROXY port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4... connected
* Connected to MYPROXY (1.2.3.4) port 80 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:21
* Proxy auth using Basic with user '****'
* Server auth using Basic with user 'MYUSER\****'
> CONNECT MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:21 HTTP/1.1
> Host: MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:21
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxx-xxx-xxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.0
< 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
< 220 Microsoft FTP Service
> USER MYUSER\****
< 331 Password required
> PASS ****
< 230 User logged in.
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> CWD site
< 250 CWD command successful.
> CWD wwwroot
< 250 CWD command successful.
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||10201|)
*   Trying 1.2.3.4... connected
* Connecting to MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net (1.2.3.4) port 80
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:10201
* Proxy auth using Basic with user '****'
* Server auth using Basic with user 'MYUSER\****'
> CONNECT MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:10201 HTTP/1.1
> Host: MYSITE.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net:10201
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic xxxxx
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
< Proxy-Agent: Zscaler/6.0
< 

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I.
> STOR web.config
< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
} [data not shown]

104   521    0     0  104   521      0    201  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--   204* Remembering we are in dir "site/wwwroot/"

104   521    0     0  104   521      0    145  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:--   146
104   521    0     0  104   521      0    113  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:--   114
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     93  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    93
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     79  0:00:06  0:00:06 --:--:--   128
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     68  0:00:07  0:00:07 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     60  0:00:08  0:00:08 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     54  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     49  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     44  0:00:11  0:00:11 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     41  0:00:12  0:00:12 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     38  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     35  0:00:14  0:00:14 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     33  0:00:15  0:00:15 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     31  0:00:16  0:00:16 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     29  0:00:17  0:00:17 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     28  0:00:18  0:00:18 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     26  0:00:20  0:00:19  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     25  0:00:20  0:00:20 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     24  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     23  0:00:22  0:00:22 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     22  0:00:23  0:00:23 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     21  0:00:24  0:00:24 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     20  0:00:26  0:00:25  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     19  0:00:27  0:00:26  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     18  0:00:28  0:00:27  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     18  0:00:28  0:00:28 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     17  0:00:30  0:00:29  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     17  0:00:30  0:00:30 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     16  0:00:32  0:00:31  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     15  0:00:34  0:00:32  0:00:02     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     15  0:00:34  0:00:33  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     15  0:00:34  0:00:34 --:--:--     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     14  0:00:37  0:00:35  0:00:02     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     14  0:00:37  0:00:36  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     13  0:00:40  0:00:37  0:00:03     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     13  0:00:40  0:00:38  0:00:02     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     13  0:00:40  0:00:39  0:00:01     0
104   521    0     0  104   521      0     12  0:00:43  0:00:40  0:00:03     0< 425 Data channel timed out.
* server did not report OK, got 425

104   521    0     0  104   521      0     12  0:00:43  0:00:40  0:00:03     0* Connection #0 to host MYPROXY left intact

curl: (18) server did not report OK, got 425
> QUIT
< 221 Goodbye.
* Closing connection #0
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried with explicit passive mode, `--ftp-pasv`, and/or `--ftp-skip-pasv-ip`?

Comment: Btw, you missed one Basic proxy auth creds..

Comment: @randomir Same behaviour with these args: sometimes it works, sometimes not. I just noticed: When I look into my remote site, I can see the file is appearing for some seconds and then disappears. // What do you mean with *one Basic proxy auth creds*?

Comment: If it is resolved,please add an answer here to help more communities easily to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was that I had to enter a different proxy server. As I learned, my company has different proxies: some for "normal" users and some for servers. The proxy used by the servers don't require basic auth. With this proxy, it works now.